# How can I get around the texture and video memory limitations in SDL2?

Tags: textures, sdl

I tested the max texture size and the max number of textures I can have in SDL2 and it's limited to 23 textures of 16384 x 16384 pixels. After that it runs out of video memory, as per the SDL_GetError() message I get.

Surely AAA games are displaying more than 23 textures of 16384 x 16384 pixels in the game world, every frame. So how do they do that without running out of video memory? They can't be constantly loading from disk. It has to be saved to video ram already when the game loads. So why is SDL2 limiting me to 23 textures of 16384 x 16384 pixels? Is there a way around that?

I am programming a 2d game and would like to load the entire game world from the start, so that the player does not have a load screen once they start playing.

Currently, the work around I'm thinking of programming is to have only the large game background textures recomposed every time the player enters a new area but the rest of the game elements will all be loaded at the start of the game. That way there will only be a fraction of a second of black screen during which the large textures are recomposed for the new area. But still I would like to not have to load or blackout anything at all during gameplay, given the type of game I am making. I am trying to make a fully immersive sim game.

Comment: *"Surely AAA games are displaying more than 23 textures of 16384 x 16384 pixels in the game world, every frame"* I wouldn't be so sure. Those are huge textures, assuming they're uncompressed and 32-bit-per-pixel, each one is 1GB large.

Comment: I timed how long it would take the player to make a character in my game walk from one side of a texture to ther other and it would take around two minutes. That is a very small map given what I'm going for. AAA games (rpgs for example) have much larger maps; they must be loading textures and creating maps on the fly. How do they do that without freezing the game? Maybe they do freeze the game and are doing it under 30 frames per second or maybe they load the maps portion by portion so that it's imperceptible?

Comment: How is map size connected to texture size? The textures on terrain are usually repeated, they don't need to be huge.

Comment: In order to not iterate through thousands of textures on the map/layer each frame I am creating a large texture composed of these smaller textures when the game starts, before the player takes control. I have in the past done it the way you mentioned but it instantly killed the frame rate as soon as I added multiple layers for parallax scrolling.

Comment: Sorry, there should be a comma after "map/layer each frame": map/layer each frame,

Comment: Aha, so it was an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain how your rendering works (used to work before you decided to add the huge textures)? Why and how you "iterate through thousands of textures"?

Comment: Basically I had it so the game world was made up of multiple layers drawn in the following order: first parallax layer, second parallax layer, ground layer, object layer, third parallax and fourth parallax. Each frame, each of those layers would be rendered from 16 x 16 textures loaded in memory outside of the main game loop. The issue was that iterating through each of the 16 x 16 tile that make up the layers was killing the frame rate. So I decided to render those layers outside of the main game loop and creating large textures for each.

Comment: That way I only have to iterate through 6 large textures and that fixed the frame rate. The large textures are stored in vram and the gpu is doing the renderering and that is much much faster.

Comment: Was each 16x16 tile a separate texture? If so, you need to use a texture atlas (meaning, a large texture where each tile appears **once**). This should make things faster without requiring tons of memory.

Comment: Each texture was a 16 x 16 SDL_Texture* type and there would be only one for each tile type. When the renderer would draw to screen each frame, it would render the texture at specific coordinates on screen based on a tile map vector. Like what is explained here (https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/39_tiling/index.php). The problem is not the memory but the cpu processing power needed to iterate through each tile data in the tile map. The tile data would be the index of the texture that needed to be drawn on screen.

Comment: You're iterating over the visible tiles only, right? (ones in the view rectangle) Doing this (plus making a texture atlas) should make things fast enough.

Comment: For example you would have a tile map like std::vector<std::vector<int>> tileMap, where the first vector list would be the X and the second the Y coordinates. The int would be the index of the texture: std::vector<int> SDL_Texture* textures. So then you iterate through the tile map to get the index of the sdl texture to render on screen, and the coordinates to render at would match the X and Y when you're iterating through the tile map multiplied by tile size: so each tile would render at X * 16, Y * 16 coordinates on screen. Iterating through all those was the bottleneck.

Comment: The iteration of `tileMap` itself can't be a bottleneck, unless you're iterating over the whole map rather than the visible region. I did this in several games, and didn't have performance problems. If you only iterate over the visible region, then your bottleneck must be rendering, and rendering can be made faster by putting all the textures into a single texture atlas (a big texture where each of the original textures appears once), because switching between different textures is not free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just implemented and tested rendering tiles each frame. That's 5100 tiles to render in the camera view per layer, for 2 layers, each frame. So 10200 tiles (textures) to render on screen each frame. It brought the frame rate down to 20 compared to 60 and above using my method of pre-rendered large textures. So this proves my point, that CPUs are not fast enough to iterate through that many elements, even though each tile is a texture already loaded in vram. It is much faster to render an area of 1 large texture to the screen, compared to rendering 5100 smaller textures, each frame, even when these textures are all located in the same file that is loaded into one texture before the main game loop. Which is the point I was trying to make in my discussion with HolyBlackCat.

So this circles back to my original question on this post: How can I get around the texture and video memory limitations in SDL2?

The video memory limitation does not seem to be related to SDL2 but to the hardware (the graphics card), which makes sense. So I will stick with my solution of splitting the game world into areas and every time the player enters a new area, the large textures for it will be pre-rendered.

Comment: I have to agree, 10k tiles is too much to render this way. I think last time I tried it, I was able to do at most 8k at 60 fps. But I doubt that the iteration itself over the array is slow, it's the rendering itself that's slow.

Comment: Yes, it might be the rendering but I'm also iterating over other objects in my game: buildings, light sources, characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the pipeline you have in whatever engine you created.
You can see by this video I push 40,000 moving objects at nearly 60fps.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=408DkNLuhUU
I am running an old system. graphics card is rx570 and on a 3ghz cpu.
If I wasn't moving all of those circles around I could push a lot more.
That video is of the C++ engine I am running.
I made a python version of it that gets 3000 circles moving at 60fps or around the same thing you are at 20fps.You can find it https://github.com/hayesgr/PySDL2-Engine
You can also find a video on the same channel of a 40,000 room dungeon generated in 1 second. It's tile based and huge.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIqPJWl8afw&t=233s

16384x16384 images are 1Gb in size. You won't fit many of those on most video cards. If you update using those it will be costly as heck.

The point here is you are looking at the wrong solution for what you want.
If you look at the python version of my engine you will see it is state based.
My C++ engine also uses multi-threading for dealing with the movement and collision calculations. If I didn't have those moving parts. I wouldn't need the multi-threading to push that to the screen. In short the multi-threading I use isn't for pushing stuff to screen purely for reducing computational time.
I can push probably 50,000 or so to screen at 60fps if I wasn't moving them all.

If you also look on the same channel you will see I have terrain generators as well. So building a huge world in a very short time is entirely possible. You just need to write efficient code.